# Files and images aren't visible when using URL, but work when using the IP address

Tags: jsp, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, tomcat6

I am working on a classic jsp app hosted on ubuntu/tomcat6 recently moved from rackspace to AWS. When I pull up the site using the IP address I can access files and images under the webroot/userFiles folder. When I access it off the URL, these same files and images return a 404 error. Everything else on the site works fine under either convention.

In other words this works:

http://xx.xx.xx.xx/userFiles/image1234.png

this does not work (returns 404):

http://mainsiteurl.com/userFiles/image1234.png

Any idea what could be causing the 404? I can see the DNS resolve appropriately and everything else on the site seems to return just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the people that had setup the server had installed the site twice and hadn't configured it correctly. One was in the base tomcat install and one was in a separate folder. I basically had to clean out one of the sites all together and treat the server (correctly) as having just one site installed. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell an answer without further troubleshooting. So, after the DNS resolution what do you get in the browser Network trace? Use Chrome Dev Tools (or similar) to inspect the request/response conversation with server. Is there any URL redirection when requesting through a URL instead of IP? Also, can you check tomcat logs (or URL rewrite module) to find a bit more about what happens to the request, server-side?

Comment: So a look at the Network trace on chrome dev tools had nothing overly interesting. The site starts with a couple of 302's to ensure login, but the pages with the images looked basically identical except for the paths being based on IP vs. URL.

The more interesting thing was found in tracing the logs on tomcat. Only the IP address HTTP calls are registering in the logs. Anything using the base URL doesn't appear in the logs.... is this something that could occur with URL rewrite? I am admittedly unfamiliar with that function.

Comment: If you don't detect the URL requests I don't think so. Is the resolved DNS the IP of your tomcat server or some reverse proxy or intermediate server instead? Are you able to trace the request from your end to the tomcat server? Is the 404 response from tomcat or another intermediate server? Can you inspect the HTTP response headers to determine the server that issued the response?

Comment: Just saw the installation details below :) that certainly explains the 404 Cheers!